# Sun elevation calculation using nrel

Tags: c, math, geometry, astronomy

I am looking for a formula to calculate sun elevation angle from the below data. I have downloaded data into an Excel sheet by providing the required latitudes and longitudes.

Questions are:

1. How do I calculate elevation angle from zenith and azimuth angle?
2. What is refer Top. azimuth angle (westward from S) & Top. azimuth angle (eastward from N) from image
3. What is converted elevation formula to determine elevation angle from east to west?

[image: Data got from Nrel calculator]
[image: d2]

[Nrel calculator](https://www.nrel.gov/midc/solpos/spa.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an astronomy related program, not about programming per se.

Answer (score 1):

Elevation angle MIGHT BE the complement of zenith angle (i.e., 90 minus zenith angle). To verify that, and to find out the definitions of all the angles they use, look at the paper linked from the web page about the NREL calculator software: https://www.nrel.gov/midc/spa/